# Manipulate Dataframe Series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, data-manipulation

I have a dataframe and I want to change some element of a column based on a condition.
In particular given this column:

```
...    VALUE    ....
       0
       "1076A"
       12
       9
       "KKK0139"
       5
```

I want to obtain this:

```
...    VALUE    ....
       0
       "1076A"
       12
       9
       "0139"
       5
```

In the 'VALUE' column there are both strings and numbers, when I found a particular substring in a string value, I want to obtain the same value without that substring.
I have tried:

```
1) df['VALUE'] = np.where(df['VALUE'].str.contains('KKK', na=False), df['VALUE'].str[3:], df['VALUE'])

2) df.loc[df['VALUE'].str.contains('KKK', na=False), 'VALUE'] = df['VALUE'].str[3:]
```

But these two attempts returns a IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable

Some advice ?

Comment: If you want to replace substring in string value, why the `A` in "1076A" is not removed ?  Only string at the start of text ?

Comment: Yes, I want to remove only a particular substring at the start of the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the column contains both numeric value (non-string) and string values, **you cannot use `.str.replace()`** since it handles strings only. You have to use [`.replace()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) instead.  Otherwise, non-string elements will be converted to `NaN` by `str.replace()`.

Here, you can use:

```
df['VALUE'] = df['VALUE'].replace(r'KKK', '', regex=True)
```

**Input:**

```
data = {'VALUE': [0, "1076A", 12, 9, "KKK0139", 5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

**Result:**

```
0        0
1    1076A
2       12
3        9
4     0139
5        5
Name: VALUE, dtype: object
```

If you use `.str.replace()`, you will get:

**Note the `NaN` values result for numeric values (not of string type)**

```
0      NaN
1    1076A
2      NaN
3      NaN
4     0139
5      NaN
Name: VALUE, dtype: object
```

#### In general, if you want to remove leading alphabet substring, you can use:

```
df['VALUE'] = df['VALUE'].replace(r'^[A-Za-z]+', '', regex=True)
```

Comment: Very comprehensive answer, thanks SeaBean

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> df['VALUE'].str.replace(r'KKK', '')
0        0
1    1076A
2       12
3        9
4     0139
5        5
Name: VALUE, dtype: object
```

Comment: Is that what the OP wants?

Comment: @Vishnudev, Now probably.

Comment: Yes. +1 @Corralien. You don't need `regex=True` now

Answer (score 0):

Your second solution fails because you also need to apply the row selector to the right side of your assignment.

```
df.loc[df['VALUE'].str.contains('KKK', na=False), 'VALUE'] = df.loc[df['VALUE'].str.contains('KKK', na=False), 'VALUE'].str[3:]
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your sample data, if `k` is the only problem, just replace it with empty string

```py
df['VALUE'].str.replace('K', '')
0          0
1    "1076A"
2         12
3          9
4     "0139"
5          5
Name: text, dtype: object
```

If you want to do it for specific occurrences or positions of k, you can do that as well.